# How I can get css selector from the found element in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

cy.get('div').contains('foo') => return element
I need get css selector from this element.
Because cy.screenshot({blackout: ''}) expect css selector...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, however it seems like you could use

```
'div:contains("foo")'
```

as a selector in your code. Please let me know if it works in your case.